# Openmp thread affinity: Set 2 threads in the program, how many cores are running?

Tags: c++, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, openmp, affinity

I wrote an Openmp Program, running it on a two core machine.

When I changed the thread number from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 4, I couldn't get the 2x speed up.

2 threads to 4 threads, that's the hyperthreads. Hyperthreads generally can't get 2x speed up because of resources limitation.

However, 1 threads to 2 threads, still can't get the 2x speed up, I feel confused about this.I searched and found the CPU affinity concept, but I can't figure out how Openmp works.

When I use 2 threads, does Openmp static schedule arrange 2 threads into 1 core or 2 core?

omp_get_thread_num() function can't tell me the answer since the return value is 0 or 1, but I don't know they are running on 1 core or 2.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Without code its hard to answer because we would mostly guess whats happening. For starters: omp_get_thread_num() returns the thread identifier. So Thread 1 returns 0 and Thread 2 - 1 and so on.

Comment: The usual method to assign 2 threads to separate cores in spite of hyperthreading is with omp_places=cores.  If your openmp doesn't support this you may need more threads than cores in order to get full use of all cores.

Comment: Can I write some code to find out which core is Thread 1 running on, which core is Thread 2 running on?

Answer (score 1):

Can use thread affinity with **proc_bind**:

Close
[image]

Spread
[image]

Master
[image]

I hope this will help you choose the appropriate option to work.

Comment: Thanks, Ruslan. I am trying to use the thread affinity of OpenMP, however, It's easy to set environment variable of OpenmP in Linux, but doesn't work in VS, on Windows Platform.

Comment: Works, if you use Intel Compiler. Compiler from VS support only OpenMP 2.0, in this link on Intel web-site you can find this information   https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522691

Comment: Thanks, Ruslan. I changed the Compiler from VC++ into Intel so that I can use the proc_bind setting.